Is it permissible to visit my brothers house although im not married?
My brother (in his late twenties) recently moved out of my parents house. I (female, in my early twenties) thought this was not a big deal as I thought I could visit him. However my parents said I can’t go to his house on my own until I'm married because it’s not permissible in Islam. When I tell them to elaborate they tell me I won’t understand. I really don’t understand how visiting my own brother isn’t permissible in Islam, if it was a male friend I would totally understand but this is my brother. I don’t think my parents would lie and if they aren’t I need a clear explanation.

Maybe you are missing some detail. For example if he lives far away it is forbidden for a woman to travel alone without being accompanied by a mahram, or if he is not your biological brother but rather a step brother or adopted, or if he is not righteous and hence could harbor ill-intentions. There could be a number explanations for your parent's behavior, including simply being a misconception - we can't really guess.

That’s the thing, none of those things apply, that’s why I find it so odd. I just would like to know where it’s written that I’m not allowed to visit him. I’ve tired speaking about it to my parents but they always beat around the bush and eventually get mad therefore asking them directly is of no help and never gets anywhere. Nonetheless, thank you for your response I appreciate it!
